# Bash script that that determine if string "a" is the same for "x" hours then do "Y"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, aix

hope this is not a repost.

I am trying to insert a line in my script that determine if the value of a string file is the same for "x" hours (1-2 hours) than send  mail. This is my logic

```
if [[ "${LAST_VALUE}" -eq 1 for "x" hours  ]]; then
    mails -s .....
else
echo "The value has been changed"
fi
```

The problem is that idk how to write this for bash.
Many Thx guys!

Comment: Is your system in a sort of loop? Or how does this script run? Is it constantly rerun in a cronjob or is it constantly run in a loop or does the script itself contains a loop? Also, where do you get the value assigned to `LAST_VALUE`?

Comment: It runs in a cronjob. And it takes values from my DB and insert it in some outputs.
The problem is how do I check my ${LAST_VALUE}" (this is an output) if it is -eq to "1"  for more then "x" then do "y"

Answer (score 1):

From your comments I gather that you can extract the value of `LAST_VALUE` by means of some database query or some external command. Lets call it `db_query`. My suggestion would be to have an external file that contains this value and the time it was changed.

Let's assume we have the file: `/tmp/dbquery.txt` and contains a line like:

```
 key epoch value
```

Then we can have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# read old value
read -r key old_epoch old_value < /tmp/dbquery.txt

# query and store new values
last_value="$(dbquery)"
last_epoch="$(date "+%s")"

if [[ "${last_value}" == "${old_value}" ]]; then
   echo $key $old_epoch $old_value > /tmp/dbquery.txt
else        
   echo $key $last_epoch $last_value > /tmp/dbquery.txt
fi

if [[ "${last_value}" == 1 ]] && (( last_epoch - old_epoch > 3600 )); then
   do stuff
fi
```